# Set database column alias before exporting csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export, alias

Hey guys I am trying to export a csv in my script and it works perfectly. Now what I need to do, is rename the columns to clean names and proper names before fully exporting the csv.

Here is a picture of the database table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C8Kb.png

Here is the code:

```
include_once "config.php";

$table = 'patients'; // table you want to export
$file  = 'export'; // csv name.

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . ""); 
$i      = 0;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $csv_output .= $row['Field'] . ",";
    $i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $table . "");

while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
    $csv_output .= $rowr[$j] . ", ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file . "_" . date("d-m-Y_H-i", time());

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".csv");

print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

As you can see it fetches the table names from this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . ""); 
$i      = 0;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $csv_output .= $row['Field'] . ",";
    $i++;
}
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is allow it to rename the database tables from
pat_id to Patient ID
pat_fname to Patient First Name
pat_lname to Patient Last name
and so on. To make it looks neat and readable in the csv file.

How am I able to do that? I already tried a few codes like:

```
$query = 'SHOW COLUMNS pat_id AS "user_id", pat_fname AS "first name", pat_lname AS "last name" FROM ' . $table;
```

But it didnt work and gives off errors.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use friendly column names in your `select`, not your `show columns`.

Try something like this instead of `SELECT *` :

```
   $query = "SELECT pat_id AS 'user_id', pat_fname AS 'first name', pat_lname AS 'last name' FROM table";
```

Notice that MySQL expects your column names to be shown in single quotes, not double quotes.

To handle this stuff as column headers in csv ... try this.

```
$values = mysql_query($query);
$i = mysql_num_fields($values);
for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
   $csv_output .= mysql_field_name($j) . ", ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
      $csv_output .= $rowr[$j] . ", ";
  }
  $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

Comment: This will return the field values and not the field names.

Comment: I did that, and now it doesnt show the column names when I export the csv. I think it HAS to be show columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to deal with many tables, create a multidimensional array and predefine the field names in it.

Like this, 
$tables['table1'][1]="";
$tables['table1'][2]="";
$tables['table2'][1]="";

Then replace this block,

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field'] . ",";
$i++;
}
}
```

with a block to fetch the field names of the table from your array.
This is the only way to do it.

Comment: There will be only one table it deals with and thats 'patients' table basically the table csv exporting. Could you show me the array and il add onto it.

Comment: **Prototype:** $patients[0]="store the first field" .... $patients[n]="store the nth field";

Comment: Where exactly does the $patients variable get used in the whole script?

Comment: Now how do I rearange around the second part where it lists the rows, I would like the column Last Name to come before First Name and Location to come after IME Date.

Comment: **use this line to replace the old one in your script** `$values = mysql_query("SELECT pat_id,pat_lname,pat_fname,pat_date,pat_loc,pat_ins,pat_show  FROM " . $table . "");`

Comment: One last thing, I made this query so it combines 2 tables into one so It can get the name of the office and insurance company instead of the number variable it is but its not working.$values = mysql_query("SELECT pat_id,pat_lname,pat_fname,pat_date,pat_loc,pat_ins,pat_show FROM patients INNER JOIN offices ON office_id = pat_loc INNER JOIN insurance ON ins_id = pat_ins ");

Comment: I am trying to get it to show the name Brooklyn instead of a 2 for the Location. How can I get that to work?